# Is it possible to cut video based on audio?

Tags: audio

I wonder if any of you guys know some solution and can help a small team of inexprienced (in terms of video) podcasters. We're producing our Audio podcast in a purely audio editing software (Reaper) and do quite some cuts after the show to trim it as good as possible.

We're thinking about adding video for some shows and wonder if there's a way to bring these cuts to the video. The video will mostly be just recorded faces talking to each other so there's no need for perfection in terms of video - it's basically just a by-product. The idea is to find a way to minimize the additional work and to be able to use the audio that runs through some layers of cutting and effects as a base for the video but that would mean the cuts made on the audio needed to go into the video.

We're hoping for some solution that's similar to syncing multicam through audio. Any idea?

Comment: Why not reverse your workflow? Edit the video (with the audio) and then export the audio only for the podcast after you finish?

Comment: So, you have multiple clips with video and audio, and you also have a single finished audio podcast. The goal is to assemble and cut video clips according to the podcast. Have you tried Pluraleyes? I am not sure it can do exactly that, but it is designed for audio sync, so it might be something that you can use.

Comment: How long is a typical show, and do you record the audio in one continuous take?